Здравствуйте, в проекте Django есть 2 функции выборки, почему только одна из них выводит данные в html шаблон?
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Books
from django.views.generic import DetailView
# Create your views here.


def books_date(request):

    new = Books.objects.order.by('date')
    return render(request, 'books/books_home.html', {'new': new})
def books_home(request):

    books = Books.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'books/books_home.html', {'books': books})


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Во-первых, какая? Во-вторых, что вы предприняли для того, чтобы шаблон вообще что-то выводил?
